# How can I download Amazon S3 EBS snapshot to my pc?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

Hey I am new to AWS and I am using it with image imported from vmware vsphere now I took snapshots to my instance. I want to download an image to my pc like I am doing with vsphere but I can not. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you provide more informtion. Are you trying to download an Amazon S3 object using an AWS SDK. If do, what language are you using.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmexport_image.html

Comment: @smac2020 I am using AWS CLI and AWS console itself

Comment: @jordanm no , I want the snapshot itself to my pc as I intend to use it in memory forensics tool

Comment: @EmadAboelnasr once its exported to S3 you can just download it to your PC from there.

Comment: @jordanm sorry but how I can't export the snapshot itself

Comment: @EmadAboelnasr You can create an AMI from the snapshot, which will include all the contents of the snapshot. Then you can follow the link I posted for exporting the AMI.